# задачка по JavaScript с массивами

Tags: javascript

задание Вносим n-oе количество элементов массива
        Выводим исходный массив и максимальную серию 
подряд идущих положительных элементов (по возрастанию с шагом +1)
[1,3,6,5,6,7,8,4,1,4,5] -> максимальная серия [5,6,7,8]

вот что получается пока у меня

```
var mas=[];

do {
    mas.push(+prompt('Введите число'))
} while(mas[mas.length-1]!=0)

mas.pop();
console.log(mas.join(" "));

var max=mas[0];
for (var i=0;i < mas.length;i++){
    if(mas[i]>max) max=mas[i];
}

console.log("Максимальные числа в массиве =",max);
```

не могу разобраться как узнать серию и из нее выбрать положительные числа...

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('run').onclick = () => {

    var mas = document.getElementById('input').value.split(',').map(i => +i);
    let max=0, max_series=[];
    mas.reduce((result,item) => {
        //Сначала разбиваем массив на серии
 let series = result[result.length-1];
 if(series && item === (1 + series[series.length-1])){
  series.push(item);
 }else{
  result.push([item]);
 }
 return result;
    },[]).reduce((max_length,series)=>{
        //потом ищем самую длинную
 if(max<series.length){
            //здесь можно изменить условие, 
            //например, найти серию с самой большой суммой чисел
            max = series.length;
            max_series= series;
 }
 return max;
    }, max);

    console.log("Самая длинная серия - ", max_series);

}
```

```html
<textarea id='input'>
0,6,2,1,4,5,6,7,1,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,2,7,8,21,4,8,9,4,1,3,4
</textarea>
<button id='run'>Run</button>
```

Проверка, что в серии только положительные числа - на вашей совести)

Comment: спасибо =)буду разбираться)